# Google Form Limit to Number of Dropdown Options

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

Previously, I was using Google Apps Script to populate the choices for a dropdown list question in Google Forms on a weekly basis.  One question had as many as 3600 choices at one time.  This week, when running the same script with a reduced number of choices (approx. 2000), I receive the following error via script.google.com:  "Failed to set choices.  You exceeded the maximum number of choices."  Is there a new limit to number of choices that can be added?  I cannot find one listed anywhere on the web.

Code snippet to reproduce the issue:

```
var sheetUrl = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/edit';
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(sheetUrl).getSheetByName("Form Responses 1");
var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
var formExample = FormApp.openById('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
var listOfCustomers= formExample.getItemById(1234567890);
var customerChoices = [];
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i+=1){
  customerChoices.push(listOfCustomers.asListItem().createChoice(data[i][0]));
}
listOfCustomers.asListItem().setChoices(customerChoices);
```

Comment: looks like max items is 1000, I dont see it in the doc either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63395462

mc...@google.com    #4 Jul 18, 2017 01:55PM

Status: Won't Fix (Intended Behavior)
Since June, we've imposed a limit on the number of options that can be added to a Forms dropdown in Apps Script. The limit is currently 1,000 but is subject to change. If you need to provide more options, consider a free-form text field, multiple dropdowns, or a custom web form.

Comment: The limit seems to be well below 1k now -- I tried adding a drop down with ~300 questions and it fails to save.

Comment: Apparently if you break down your 300 answer choices into groups and add them incrementally google can handle it... so maybe the 1k limit still applies.

Comment: @Afflatus Hmm, are you using .setChoices() and is that the line that fails?  I added 959 choices/options to one GForm question only a few minutes ago using a method mirroring my code above.

Comment: @AleisterTanekJavasMraz - No, I wasn't using the API, I was going straight from the user / consumer interface.

Answer (score 1):

While this solution doesn't address the limit imposed on scripts (as of 2022/9/8 it's still 1000) it does provide a manual work-around for someone who doesn't need to automate the process.

Using manual copy-and-paste I have successfully created dropdowns with more than 1000 entries.

Steps:

1. Copy (ctrl + c) a list of more than 1000 items (from Google Sheets, for example)
2. Create an empty dropdown in a Google Form
3. Paste (ctrl + v) the list of items

I created a dropdown with 1690 entries that way.

Credit for this solution goes to TC.