# How can I add more than 500 options to a DROP_DOWN question using the Google Forms API

Tags: google-api, google-forms, google-forms-api

From my research, it looks like there is a limit of 500 options to each question using the API.

More than 500 can be added if it is done through the web interface.

Is there a way to pragmatically add options to a question, either by pushing the options in several stages, or by appending to the existing data set?

```
"error": {
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Batch update failed: update results in the schema exceeding the choice limit",
  "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
}
```

I tried to add ~1000 options to a DROP_DOWN question in a Google Form, using the Google Forms API,

I was expecting to be able to push all of these at once, but there is a 500 option limit.

From what I can see you can not append options, and must re-push all options at the same time.

What actually happened was I got this error

"error": {
"code": 400,
"message": "Batch update failed: update results in the schema exceeding the choice limit",
"status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
}

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Form Limit to Number of Dropdown Options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44957814/google-form-limit-to-number-of-dropdown-options)